# How can I tell what pragmas from '__future__' have been enabled at runtime in a Python program?

Tags: python, python-2.x

When I enable an interpreter feature in Python 2 with a `from __future__ import X` statement (e.g. `from __future__ import unicode_literals`), the interpreter behavior changes from there on out.

Is there a way, at runtime, to determine what `__future__` pragmas have been  enabled at a given point in execution?

The reason I want to do this is that some legacy code I maintain conditionally enables some `__future__` pragmas before `eval`ing/runtime-importing other arbitrary code. When debugging behavior  issues in that code, I want to check whether it's because some of those conditional `__future__` imports have been triggered or not. I know that conditionally importing `__future__` (or importing it at anything other than the top of an entry point) is an antipattern and have no plans of spreading it; I  just want to debug code that does this.

I've tried checking `sys.modules`, and using that I can tell that *something* from `__future__` has been imported because the `__future__` module shows up in the already-imported list. However, that's just the `__future__` *module*, and the interpreter-behavior changes are not implemented as submodules, so I can't see which have been enabled or not.

Comment: You can test for existence. If `unicode_literals` has been imported for example, is is defined whereas null if not imported.

Comment: Is it possible that the code does something ugly, like `unicode_literals = 3` or `from __future__ import unicode_literals as ul`, etc.? If not, you can just check for the normal import that comes along with the future statement as a side effect. If so, you’ll have to get the module’s code object and check its `co_flags`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just look at the top of the file, because `__future__` imports are defined there, they can't be anywhere else.

Also the interpreter is **not changed globally** as you imply. The `__future__` changes are only for the modules that have the actual `__future__` import in them. So if you have two `.py` files in your project, and only one of them has the `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, then only **that file** will have unicode literals. The other file will still have normal literals.

The test below has been executed in python 2.7:

file1.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
x = 'This is unicode'
```

file2.py

```
y = 'This is NOT unicode'
```

Testing:

```
>>> import file1
>>> import file2
>>> file1.x, type(file1.x)
(u'This is unicode', <type 'unicode'>)
>>> file2.y, type(file2.y)
('This is NOT unicode', <type 'str'>)
```

That means the features are stored **per module** and not globally. You can check the module object for the feature attribute:

```
>>> file1.unicode_literals
_Feature((2, 6, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 131072)
>>> file2.unicode_literals
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'unicode_literals'
```